# Cannot reach the column's data?

Tags: javascript, jsom, html-form-web-part

I made a list. I want to pull the datas from this list . I used Javascript, SOAP and HTML form web part. But it cannot read the column. That returns 'undefined'. I tried only 'GroupName' instead of 'ows_GroupName'. But nothing's changed.

```
function processResult(xData, status) { 
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {
        var title=$(this).attr("ows_Title"); 
        var GroupName=$(this).attr('ows_GroupName'); 
        var STR = "<li><h3>" + title + GroupName +"</h3>";
        STR +="</li>"; 

        $("#list").append(STR);
    });
}
```

Comment: what version of sharepoint is it? does "ows_GroupName" exist? can you print out the full xml to see if it exists? $("#list").append(xData.responseXML);

Comment: Version is 2010. and yes i added the column name. And also see it in  u2u Caml Query. But that is only undefined $(this).attr('ows_GroupName')  in section.

Comment: in u2u caml what does it show the fieldname as? cant you use the internal name instead of ows?